# Next.js 13 app directory Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-server-components

I'm using Next.js 13's new `app` directory feature and have a page component at `app/page.tsx` that contains the following code:

```
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";

export default async function IndexPage() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Since I need to use `useState`, I added the `'use client'` directive at the top.

But I'm getting the following error when loading the page.

```
Server Error
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the component was marked as `async` but it's a client component and there are no `await` calls within the component. Removing `async` from the component declaration fixed the issue.

```
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";

// Must not be async.
export default function IndexPage() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```